# Adding a node to a linked list stack in C

Tags: c, list, linked-list, stack

So I've got this code already: http://pastebin.com/3wuFNWGA

And I've got these typedefs in a .h file: http://pastebin.com/JTG9XHvW

I need my push function to add a node to my_stack by allocating memory for the node, storing the data (new element) in the node, and inserting the node at the top of the stack. The code runs but when I try to print the value in my_stack->top->data after pushing a new value onto the stack, it always prints zero and not the element I supposedly pushed onto the stack.

For the life of me, I can't figure out why. I don't think there's a problem arising when I create the new node and store the value in data so I'm thinking there's a problem when I try to make my_stack->top point to the most recently added node?

This is also my first post on Stack Overflow.  I hope I did everything right.

Here's the push function to push a value onto the stack:

```
void push( Stack *my_stack, int newElement ) {
    Node_s *newNode;
    newNode = (Node_s *) malloc(sizeof(Node_s));
    if( newNode == NULL ) {
            printf("Error: malloc failed in push\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    newNode->data = newElement;
    newNode->next = my_stack->top;
    my_stack->top = newNode;
}
```

Comment: Please add the *relevant* parts of your code to the body of the thread

Comment: I added the push function to the body.  I believe that's the relevant part to this problem but I'm not entirely sure what the problem is so it's hard to pinpoint the relevant part.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the issue, but note that you don't modify `size` when you push an element. Also: can you also add the the sample input+output and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will print zero for the size of the stack as you never increase that.

Also it prints 0 for the element because the type of the data field is declared as `double` but you print it with integer specificator.

Changing:

```
printf("The value at the top of the stack is %d\n", my_stack->top->data);
```

to

```
printf("The value at the top of the stack is %lf\n", my_stack->top->data);
```

Fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear!

check this:

```
typedef struct Node_s {
  double data;
  struct Node_s* next;
}Node_s;
```

data is defined as double.

But here...

```
push(my_stack, 100);
```

you try to push a int.

So... maybe your check the push to `push(my_stack, 100.00);` or the `typedef struct Node_s` to:

```
typedef struct Node_s {
   int data;
   struct Node_s* next;
 }Node_s;
```

Comment: The conversion is not a problem. The problem is only with the output specificator.

Comment: Of course it would be some tiny mistake.  How embarrassing.  Thanks so much for the help, everyone!  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah. The problem is the printf %d!

Comment: Yep.  Had to change it in the printf and realized I needed to change it in the parameters for my void push function.  I also needed to add an increment to size, which I had forgotten.  Lot of silly mistakes revealed to me by posting this but I'm glad I at least had the right idea as far as implementation goes.